# Pre-commit hook that checks svn:externals for tags directory

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-externals, externals

I'm trying to check my externals through an SVN Pre-commit hook. The svn:external contains an shared library through multiple projects. On the Pre-commit hook, I want to check if the external is pointing to a Tag directory and not to the trunk or a branch.

At my local machine in the working copy folder, I could successfully run the command:

```
svn propget svn:externals
```

This returned me the external:

```
https://SVNSERVER/svn/Test_Lib/trunk Test_Lib
```

Although this works on my local machine, I cannot use a svn command in the Pre-Commit hook, therefore I need a svnlook command.

And here starts my problem, I've tried multiple commands on my Pre-Commit hook, like:

```
svnlook propget %REPOS% svn:externals -t %TXN%
```

Fully written out that is:

```
svnlook propget C:\Repositories\Test_Project svn:externals -t 31-2y
```

I've tried multiple ways of placing the `%REPOS%` and `%TXN%`, with and without quotation marks around them `("%REPOS%", "%TXN%")` and moving it before and after the svn:externals part.

Unfortunately, everything I tried results in an error message that the propname or repository path is missing

> ```
> svnlook: E205001: Try 'svnlook help' for more info
> svnlook: E205001: Missing propname or repository path argument
> ```

I've searched Stack Overflow, and found 1 person who had the same problem, but he didn't got an answer on his question:

[Trying to create a pre-commit hook that verify externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013918/trying-to-create-a-pre-commit-hook-that-verify-externals#comment35237563_23029038)

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this, or a different way to request the svn:externals through the Pre-commit hook?

Comment: He **got** answer (from me), just didn't accept it. Which problems *you* have with this (older) answer? Can you see error in your parameters-list?

Comment: @LazyBadger Ok, maybe I understood your answer wrong. As far as I thought, you're checking an external of `svnlook pg rep svn:externals tags/1.0.1/ -r 7` and of `svnlook pg rep svn:externals trunk/ -r 6`, but those are already commited and in the repository, right? And I want to check them before I commit them to the repository. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct. For transaction you have *to start* from `-t %TXN%` and *your path* to externals-container in your repo

Comment: @LazyBadger, _your path_, is this the path to my working copy on my local machine? For example `D:\Projects\Test_Project`, which is on my local PC, and not the `%REPOS%` parameter in the script, which is `C:\Repositories\Test_Project` at the SVN Server PC? If so, how do I parse this local path to the script? Because as far as I know, the only parameters I get in the Pre-Commit hook script are `%TXN%` and `%REPOS%`?

Comment: No, path is *relative path inside repo-tree* `svnlook pg %REPOS% svn:externals %PATH/IN/REPO% -t %TXN%`

Comment: @LazyBadger Ah this makes it a little clearer. I can now create an working example, by setting `%PATH/IN/REPO%` to trunk/ When I commit using this command `svnlook pg %REPOS% svn:externals trunk -t %TXN%` it seems to work. Thanks for the help, I think this `%PATH/IN/REPO%`, should be based on the current branch I'm working now. I'm gonna try to fix this and will post the solution here.